# MS Edge json preview

Tags: json, microsoft-edge

Getting an API response with json `Content-Type` in Microsoft Edge prompts a download of the file, instead of displaying it in the browser. I found
[this reference](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-internet-explorer-platform/suggestions/6509717-preview-json-response-in-browser?tracking_code=edea88fcd53ce1633f5178bcb66228b0) saying that has been fixed/completed in 2015 windows 10 build 10049.

I have:

- Edition: Windows 10 Pro
- Version: 1703
- OS Build: 15063.483
- System type: 64-bit OS, x64-based processor

Is this a new bug/known issue on this build?

Answer (score 0):

Your build is old - I am on an insider build, and on 16256. Update your build, and the issue will be fixed